# Why not "Try" methods everywhere?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, api-design

I wonder, why Microsoft developers do not provide us with "Try" versions of unreliable methods everywhere?

If I use a database connection or a smtp client I always must consider exceptions:

```
try
{
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
catch (SmtpException)
{
    // test with real smtp server and analyze an exception and it's contents here
}
```

But what I want as a user is:

```
if(!smtpClient.TrySend(message, out reason))
{
    // analyze reason here
}
```

And the biggest problem for me is an exception performance overhead. I just can't afford throwing exceptions on each client call of my service. If I need to check dozens of connections/providers this can cause dozens of exceptions per each client request.

My question is: what is the rationale behind such API design decisions in .NET? I don't think that this is an error, because it is everywhere, not in a single technology.

**UPDATE**
I must give you another example of an exception in .NET to stop talking about network delays. `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry` method can throw `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` if windows service is stopped, for example.

Comment: Are you sure it's the exceptions that are causing the performance overhead and not the code you're executing in the `catch` block?  Dozens of exceptions doesn't sound all that huge in the grand scheme of things.  Note also that exception handling is much, much slower when you're hooked to the debugger.

Comment: Why not create your own methods and overloads as needed?  It's unreasonable to expect `try` methods for every possible point of failure, especially since you can wrap pretty much anything in a `try` and code from there.  Remember, you can always analyze things in your `catch`, or even call a custom method in `catch` that analyzes the exception, logs it, et cetera.

Comment: Go is an example of a language with support for exceptions, but that almost never uses them. If you get the error as a return value, you almost never ignore it, but it's not hard at all to forget to handle an exception.

Comment: @FilipHaglund: [Most exceptions don't need to be handled](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). C is an example of a language which only uses return codes, and return codes are *frequently* ignored there. The good thing about exceptions is that they do "the right thing" when they are ignored: They crash the program with a helpful error message, rather than continuing silently with an invalid state (and potentially causing harm), as is the case with return values.

Comment: "Must give you another example"  This is turning into a rant.  Exceptions are common.  They word just fine and serve the intended purpose in my opinion.  You can handle them or not.  SO cannot answer why some get Try and others do not.  Ask Microsoft.

Comment: Okey, only exceptions like file not found return error values, and if you then try to use the file pointer or whatever, you get a panic. IOException is something that should always be handeled. That's a crash that's quite easy to avoid. End users don't like when things crash, albeit letting the program run in a corrupted state is worse. If you can handle it properly, do so.

Comment: Ah, the performance. Here's the deal: exceptions do not have any performance penalty whatsoever. If used as intended that is, by an OO-minded developer. Once you start abusing them as a means of flow control to implement your algorithm... you may find they are not so fast. But that would be like using a power jigsaw for a hammer and complaining about its lack of ruggidness when you damage it.

Comment: An exception signals an error condition, something went WRONG. Once that happens, performance is no longer an issue, the original plan is aborted anyway. Getting the reason of failure to the user/programmer becomes the new goal and exceptions do that very well.

Answer (score 6):

> I wonder, why Microsoft developers do not provide us with "Try" versions of unreliable methods everywhere?

Since I'm not a Microsoft employee, I can only guess. And my guess is that this has two reasons:

- They didn't think of it when designing the first version of the .NET Class Library -- note that the `TryParse` methods have been added in later versions.
- The performance difference is not important enough (see below) to warrant the cost of implementing and maintaining the new `Try...` methods. There are other things that the .NET Framework needs more urgently.

> And the biggest problem for me is an exception performance overhead.

I **seriously** doubt that. The "performance overhead" of an SMTP timeout (= a few seconds) dominates the ["performance overhead" of throwing an exception](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions.html) (less than a millisecond) by more than a factor of 1000.

Comment: Exceptions performance is worse than this test shows, and it gets worse with newer versions of .NET. Anyway, that is not the point. There must be a reason to any performance overhead, and I don't see it.

Comment: The "performance overhead of an SMTP timeout" may be a few seconds **wall clock time**, but it is just about zero **CPU time**.  In contrast, the cost of exception handling (which is more than just throwing) is entirely CPU time.

Comment: @astef "There must be a reason to any performance overhead"   Where is that rule?

Comment: I do not accept performance reason (see update). What about new API's they develop, why there's still that exceptions there?

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you are calling a network-based service, the cost of throwing the exception per se is *not* what is killing the performance. It is the cost of finding out when to throw an exception that is the culprit: the system needs to attempt a network call, wait for it to time out or return a failure, and only then throw an exception.

The cost of actual throwing is minimal, so providing a `Try` method would not help you improve performance. It may, however, help you improve readability, which is not a small thing. To that end, you could write your own `Try` wrapper / extension method, and hide catching of the exception inside it:

```
public static bool TrySend(this SmtpClient client, object message, out Error reason) {
    try {
        client.Send(message);
        reason = null;
        return true;
    } catch (SmtpException ex) {
        reason = ex.Reason;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So their logic is: "We don't think there ever would be a need to call our method many times, so let's get rid of that nasty Try prefix"?

Comment: The cost of throwing is not minimal comparing to not throwing.

Comment: @astef no their logic is "The gain to adding a try version is less than 0.1% of the total cost, it is not worth the effort to support an additional method". Read "[Minus 100 Points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)" it does a really good job explaining why some potentially useful features are not in the framework.

Comment: Also see "[How many Microsoft employees does it take to change a lightbulb?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/)" for a look in to the hidden costs of support when "adding a simple feature".

Comment: @astef In this case the "comparison to not throwing" is not among the options, because you could either "try a network call and throw" vs. "try a network call and return normally". The "try a network call" portion of the job eclipses the timing of "throw" by orders of magnitude, when measured by wall clock time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm not asking why not to add this feature. I'm asking why it was not designed from the very beginning in an easier way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There's always a workaround, I know. And see update about performance issues

Comment: @astef not all workarounds are created equal, especially when it comes to usefulness and ease of implementation. Applicability of the `Try...` API pattern varies a great deal based on the designer's *expectation* of how "normal" or "abnormal" is a failure. If a failure is somewhat normal, designers tend to have a `Try` version (`TryParse`, `TryGetValue`, etc.) Otherwise, they stop at the version that throws an exception. It goes without saying that sometimes designers get it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

OK, you do not see the point of exceptions yet. What you are suggesting (a Try... version for everything) basically defeats the point of exceptions entirely. The beauty of exceptions is that you do not NEED to check results for each and every method call. You just assume everything will succeed (the regular case) and if one call fails it will be "caught" and handled at a predetermined place in your call stack. Your code will be ever so much more readable because it only has the steps that matter, not the plumbing. Try... is nice for scenario's that are more likely/common to "fail" and are not really errors or problems but rather just part of the normal flow control logic.

Exceptions are the OO-way, returning error codes is old school. Think about a deeply nested call hierarchy and the responsibility to handle error codes at all levels and deal with them appropriately. Compare that to using exceptions. Are you seeing the light yet? :-).

Answer (score 1):

The exception performance overhead is negligible in compare to the send / database operation you are performing.
Therefore there are scenarios (like these) that supporting the TryParse pattern is somewhat not needed.

And if you are in a scenario where you have "dozens of connections/providers" that cause "dozens of exceptions" it might be worth to check why it happens, could be a global problem with your smtp server.

P.S. Disclosure I am a Microsoft Employee, but I would answer you the same even if I was working in let's say Apple or Google :)

Comment: Recommending an investigation into why these failures are occurring is the right way to go.

Comment: This design is everywhere, not only long operations. See update

Comment: Your update again gives an example of I/O operation that again "costs" a lot more than the exception "cost".

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you don't see `Try` methods more often is that an exception communicates something. An "exceptional" condition occurs, and *something* must deal with it. The operation you just performed is so important that failure should cause the entire process to shut down. The method throwing the exception cannot handle this condition, and throwing the exception forces some block of code to handle this.

A network call is pretty critical to the successful function of your application, most times, so exceptions are appropriate. Furthermore, exceptions contain a message and the stack trace, which are essential in debugging the failure. Your proposed solution strips critical debugging information. This is not always critical, as with parsing an int, especially when it's often easy to recover from that error.

A failed network call or write to a disc is a whole different beast.

Answer (score 1):

The question is certainly justified. Taking Eric Lippert's [blog entry on exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) as a basis and given that you took the necessary precautions to make sure that Send fails because of some network condition (and not because you passed invalid arguments somewhere), I would classify SmtpException as exogenous - like File.Open, there's probably nothing you can do to prevent it. Because of this, I would not classify the SmtpException as vexing, it's not the result of bad design choices (like int.Parse).

Make sure that an SmtpException, indeed, indicates something exceptional, and exceptions will be an appropriate tool. The overhead is, like others said, negligible.